# Check if list is composed by other lists

Tags: python, list, recursion, dynamic-programming, nested-lists

I want to find out which items of the list `m` are entirely composed of items of list `w`.

If i add them into sets and make an intercept, the embedded structure becomes invisible, which is exactly what i want to avoid.

Case:

```
w= [
     ['sta'], 
     ['co', 'si'], 
     ['non'], 
     ['si'], 
     ['puo'], 
     ['ap', 'ri', 're'], 
     ['ve', 'dia', 'mo'], 
     ['co', 'sa'], 
     ['ci'], 
     ['pot', 'reb', 'be']
   ]

m=[
     ['sta', 'co'], 
     ['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'], 
     ['ve'], 
     ['dia', 'mo'], 
     ['co'], 
     ['sa'], 
     ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']
  ]
```

Desired output:

```
[['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'], ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']]
```

(e.g. `['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're']` from `m` is composed of two items from `w`: `[['puo'], ['ap', 'ri', 're']]`).

Thanks you all!

Comment: Do you just want a true/false answer from the operation? Also, unless the lists are small, seems like you'd want a to use a set and then just discard it after you're done, otherwise it will be slow.

Comment: in principle i would also like the list of the items in m that contain items from w. and the lists are big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algoithm for each element "elem" of the list "list" checks recursively if (the list elem[1:] and the list elem[:1]) or (the list elem[2:] and elem[:2]) or ... are composed by elements contained in the list w.
I also use the map "memory" to optimize the algorithm using the memoization technique.

```
def listInList(a, list, memory):
    if not list:
        return False
    elif str(list) in memory:
        return memory[str(list)]
    else:
        if list in a:
            memory[str(list)] = True
            return True
        else:
            for i in range(1,len(list)):
                if listInList(a, list[i:], memory) and listInList(a, list[:i], memory):
                    memory[str(list)] = True
                    return True
            memory[str(list)] = False
            return False

def check(a, b):
    res = []
    for elem in b:
        if listInList(a, elem, {}):
            res += [elem]
    return res

w= [
     ['sta'],
     ['co', 'si'],
     ['non'],
     ['si'],
     ['puo'],
     ['ap', 'ri', 're'],
     ['ve', 'dia', 'mo'],
     ['co', 'sa'],
     ['ci'],
     ['pot', 'reb', 'be']
   ]
m=[
     ['sta', 'co'],
     ['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'],
     ['ve'],
     ['dia', 'mo'],
     ['co'],
     ['sa'],
     ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']
  ]
print check(w,m)
```

Output:

```
[['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'], ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']]
```

Comment: so if i write this into my script and print out the list, i get a smaller sublist than i should have.

Comment: e.g. the output, if i take the lists m and w, should be exactly: [['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'], ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']]. do you know where does the difference come from? thanks!

Comment: Ok, so it is a bit more difficult. Check the new algorithm, i have edited the old one.

Comment: Thank you very much! It actually is a bit more complicated than i though it would be, but now i get what i need.

Comment: i have another question: the listinList function finds all the members of a in in members of b, but if the lists are longer, they are not exact supersets. How do i change the function to find exact supersets of members of a in members of b?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please write an example of what you mean?

Comment: the current output is [['puo', 'ap', 'ri', 're'], ['ci', 'pot', 'reb', 'be']], each of the nested lists is an exact subset of the elements in w. but if i feed in a larger list of words, my outputs are not only the supersets but also the chunks in which there is an element from a + anything else, as if it would also output the element ['sta', 'co'] from m. and i would only need the exact supersets. hope this is clearer.

Comment: I'm italian too, you can write the comment in italian if you prefer. But please give me an example of a desired output.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not italian so it's easier in english. just analysing a corpus in italian :). i'm running a segmentation algorithm; in the end i have the list of words and the list of misses, incorrectly segmented chunks. from the misses, i'd like to extract just the over-segmented chunks (so composed of full words and nothing else (['se', 'no'], ['la', 'mam', 'ma', 'ti', 'da']). the function that you proposed gives me both the over-segments and the segments that contain words + parts of neighbouring word (sth like ['im', 'pa'], ['ra', 'to']).

Comment: Although now that i went through the output again, the latter kind of outputs is very rare, i must have looked into one of the parts that has them when i first checked. Thanks again for answering!